# checking that a string contains small and big letters

Tags: ruby

I want to check that in string are small and big letters

```
a.to_s.each_byte do |s|
   if s >= 65 && s <= 90
      big = true
   elsif s >= 95 && s <= 122
      small = true
   end
end
```

Is it possible to write this in shortest form?

Comment: You can use a `regexp` but it's not clear what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to write "f" if exist big and small and "p" if don't exist

Comment: `'hello'.match? 'a-z'` etc

Comment: By small and big do you mean lower and upper case letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = a.to_s
big = true if str =~ /[A-Z]/ 
small = true if str =~ /[a-z]/
```

Answer (score 3):

If you stick to the English language then you can try something like this:

```
if a.to_s =~ /[a-z]/ and a.to_s =~ /[A-Z]/
    puts 'f'
else
    puts 'p'
end
```

But if your code needs to be able to also handle the alphabets of other languages then you should use:

```
if a.to_s =~ /[[:lower:]]/ and a.to_s =~ /[[:upper:]]/
    puts 'f'
else
    puts 'p'
end
```

Comment: Or combine them `/.*[[:lower:]].*(?=[[:upper:]])|.*[[:upper:]].*(?=[[:lower:]])/` e.g. look for the first lower and see if it followed by and upper or look for the first upper and see if it is followed by a lower

Answer (score 1):

Although I prefer the regex solutins from @axiac and @cmramseyerthis is a way your original implementementation could be made to *work*:

```
[65...90,95...122].all? do |range|
  a.to_s.each_byte.any? { |byte| range.include? byte }
end
```

In pseudocode:

> for *all* of the ranges, do *any* of the bytes fall within the range?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a candidate for the "shortest form". If both lowercase and uppercase letters are present there is either an uppercase letter following a lowercase letter or vice-versa.

```
str.match? /\p{Ll}\p{Lu}|\p{Lu}\p{Ll}/
```